# Laravel 7 Auth not working on hosted site

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

So I am trying to deploy a Laravel site to bluehost however after successful login which should redirect to '/home' and stop. It instead tries to redirect to '/home' then redirects to '/login'. the same code running on localhost with the same database works fine. Other database operations work fine.

Basically the default auth middleware seems to broken somehow.

I used laravel's built in auth to make make the authentication.
here is the live site:

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');

Auth::routes();
// Home
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//Listings
Route::get('/listings/search', 'ListingController@search')->name('search-listings');

Route::get('/listings/delete/{listing}', 'ListingController@destroy')->name('listing-delete');

Route::resource('listings', 'ListingController');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
  Route::get('/', ['as' => 'messages', 'uses' => 'MessageController@index']);
  Route::get('create', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessageController@create']);
  Route::post('/', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessageController@store']);
  Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessageController@show']);
  Route::put('/', ['as' => 'messages.update', 'uses' => 'MessageController@update']);
  Route::delete('/', ['as' => 'messages.action', 'uses' => 'MessageController@action']);
});
```

Comment: Works. You just added something to your App\Http\Controllers\LoginController.php. Open that file and check what do you return null

Comment: Works on the live site? You're able to login?

My LoginController.php doesn't return any null values. Any further explanations would be great. I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Oh sorry I left in dd() by accident. Take a look again for the behavior i was describing above. Thanks @АлександрИнженер

Comment: can u put your `loginControler` code .? and routes code

Comment: added. @KamleshPaul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there was a new line before <?php in one of my files in app/config !!

Almost drove me crazy. Worked fine on localhost but not on server. If you encounter this issue, check your .php files for new lines at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting the files in /bootstrap/cache folder except the .gitignore
then running the command `composer dumpautoload` worked